# Extract img src from string with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match-all

I've been trying to use `preg_match_all` for 30 minutes but it looks like I can't do it.

Basically I have a `$var` which contains a string of HTML code. For example:

```
<br>iihfuhuf
<img title="Image: http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg"   
 src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg">
<img src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca73b8da.jpeg"><br>
```

I want to get the `src` attribute values of `img` tags that contain `/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg` in their `src` value.

This is what I have so far:

```
preg_match_all('!(<img.*src=".*/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg"(.*alt=".*")?>)!', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: As you tried for 30 minutes...what have you come up with and what didn't work?

Comment: preg_match_all('!<img.*src="(.*/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg)"(.*alt=".*")?>!', $content, $matches); I just don't really understand how preg_match_all work. I can make the pattern but not make preg_match_all work as I expect it to work.

Comment: @MarcDupuis You should use DOM and XPath for this, not (just) regular expressions. Load the HTML into a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) and XPath for `<img>` tags with a `src` that contains `/temp/temp` and you can easily iterate the matched nodes and use a regex to extract the data you require. You can even register PHP functions with XPath to use your regex directly within the XPath query.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: Thanks for your advices but the code is generated from a wysiwyg editor and I just need to replace the src of the image before saving it into the db. So the code will always be something I expect I guess. However, thanks for making me know DOMDocument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<img[^>]*src="([^"]*/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg)"
```

`<img[^>]*` Select IMG tags

`src="([^"]*)"` gets src value and save it as a match

`/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg` is the filter for src values

For quick RegEx tests use some online tool like http://regexpal.com/

Comment: you should escape the dot `\.`

Comment: you should escape also the second " in src="([^"]*)"

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add another group to your regular expression. You have du surround everything you want to extract from the match with braces:

```
preg_match_all('!(<img.*src="(.*/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg)"(.*alt=".*")?>)!', $content, $matches);
```

You can see that working [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lBGfqc). You can find the URLs in `$matches[2]`.

But just for having said it: Regular expressions are no reasonable approach to extract anything from HTML. You would be better off using DOMDocument, XPath or something along that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/src="([^"]+temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg)"/',$url,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = '<br>iihfuhuf<img title="Image: http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg" src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg"><img src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca73b8da.jpeg"><br>';
$pattern = '#src="([^"]+/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg)"#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $out);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg"
            [1] => src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca73b8da.jpeg"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg
            [1] => http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca73b8da.jpeg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `DOMDocument`/`DOMXPath` based example of how to do it. This is arguably the only right way to do it, because unless you are *really* good at regular expressions there will most likely always be edge cases that will break your logic.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$doc->loadHTML($content);

$candidates = $xpath->query("//img[contains(@src, '/temp/temp')]");

$result = array();
foreach ($candidates as $image) {
  $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
  if (preg_match('/temp[0-9a-z]{13}\.jpeg$/', $src, $matches)) {
    $result[] = $src;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<br>iihfuhuf<img title="Image: http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg" src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca536fcd.jpeg"><img src="http://www.jlnv2.local/temp/temp513caca73b8da.jpeg"><br>';
$pattern = '#src="([^"]+/temp/temp[a-z0-9]{13}\.jpeg)"#';
    
preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $text, $match );
$src = array_pop($match);

echo $src;
```